# No autocomplete Unity sentences in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I know that the topic has been repeated many times, although I tried all the methods that I found and no solution turned out to be correct.

Visual Studio does not detect namespace from Unity:

[image: Screen from Visual Studio]

- I uninstalled and reinstalled VS
- I added VS in Unity in Preferences -> external tools
- I also did 'regenerate project files'
- after each of these options, I reset everything (VS, Unity, computer)

[image: External Tools panel in Unity]

And nothing helps. If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful. If you need any additional information, I will be happy to provide it.

- Unity 2021.1.21f1 Personal DX11
- VS 2019 [16.11.32126]

[image: Visual Studio installer]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This problem has occurred to me once before, and it was a little tricky for me to figure it out. Somewhere on your visual studio installer, there should be a way to add a package of some type, and the Unity package should be on there. Just install that into the version that you are using.

Comment: It's true, but I have added the package :(

Comment: @Mintvbz Unless it's not what I'm thinking. I added a screen from the installer. If you could see if that was what you meant

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, have you made sure that you have unity using the right version of visual studio?

Comment: Yes, in the installer there should be a Unity package somewhere.

Comment: Instead of vandalize the site and attract downvotes, please review [What should I do if no one answers my question?](/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: @Mintvbz
"Ok, have you made sure that you have unity using the right version of visual studio?"

Yeah, because i have only one ver visual studio

Comment: @RemigiuszDrobinski I read you've already uninstalled etc but starting from scratch really is the best approach: uninstall Unity and Visual Studio. Install Unity Hub and use it to install whatever version of Unity you want. In the install options will be a choice to install Visual Studio, select that and let the installer run. You will not then need to install a package, the Hub install will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default editor to open the cs file also opens vs2019, but it will not reference the correct namespace. You need to specify vs2019 in the settings to replace the default open space. In Edit-Preferences, in external tools